# OpenGL ping pong works with one pass, not with two

Tags: c++, opengl

This might be a more basic OpenGL mistake than the title suggests.

I am doing segmentation using fragment shaders in OpenGL, which require **multiple rendering passes** to do successive operations (eg. gaussian blur + edge detection + segmentation).

As far as I understood, there is this common technique called [ping pong](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis565/fbo.htm#feedback2) which takes two frame buffers (FBO) and simply renders to one FBO using the other as input.

The thing is, one pass--*shader_0* outputting stuff to *FBO_1* using *FBO_0* as input--works, but when I try to use *shader_1* with *FBO_0* as input and render into *FBO_1*, I get a **completely transparent image**.

I checked both shaders and they do work individually, yet together they produce this transparent output.

Here is the set of calls I do for each pass, with `segmentationBuffers` containing the two FBOs, respectively used as input and output for this pass:

```
glBindFramebuffer(
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    segmentationBuffers[lastSegmentationFboRenderedTo]->FramebufferName
);
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

currentStepShader->UseProgram();

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Enable blending
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

lastSegmentationFboRenderedTo = (lastSegmentationFboRenderedTo + 1) % 2;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    segmentationBuffers[lastSegmentationFboRenderedTo]->renderedTexture
);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->shaderPtr, "inputTexture"), 0);
glUniform2fv(
    glGetUniformLocation(shader->shaderPtr, "texCoordOffsets"),
    25,
    texCoordOffsets
);

quad->Draw(GL_TRIANGLES, shader,
    orthographicProjection,
    glm::mat4(1.0f),
    getOverlayModelMatrix()
);
```

And as stated above, doing one pass yields correct intermediary results, but doing two in a row gives a transparent frame. I suspect this is a more basic OpenGL mistake than it seems, but any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the call to `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`.

I suspect that by enabling depth testing, OpenGL was discarding fragments from subsequent computation steps since they had the same depth value.